# htaccess rule not working under subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this `.htaccess` rule that works fine under main domain i.e `www.example.com` but gives `404` error when the blog was migrated to subdomain i.e `blog.example.com`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ post.php?name=$1&s=$2 [L]
```

The rule is a simple `url` rewrite rule to rewrite `www.example.com/post/title/fb` to `www.example.com/post.php?name=title&s=fb`

Note: 
I should also mention that i have a `virtualhost` redirect all requests to `https`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName blog.example.com
    ServerAlias blog.example.com

    Redirect / https://blog.example.com

</VirtualHost>
```

I've checked a couple of solution here but none seem to work.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you turn `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: @Dusan Bajic Thanks alot. Yes i have RewriteEngine On

Comment: Thanks @DusanBajic.  Changing to `AllowOverride All` from `AllowOverride None` under the `<Directory var/www/html> in the `httpd.conf` file solves the problem for me.